How to insert a verb equal to a English bare infinitive into a Japanese sentence?
In English, a bare infinitive usually follows as such: subject -> transitive verb -> direct object -> bare infinitive
Example sentence: "The teacher helped me (to) study."
How would you insert this verb, "(to) study" 勉強する or other verb that would be equivalent to an English bare infinitive into a Japanese sentence.
Japanese sentence without such verb: 「先生は私を助けました。」
Where would the verb "study" go within the sentence?
Unrelated: is the particle を correct, or does it need to be some other particle like に or が?

Verb forms like する, 助ける are not any infinitives. Some linguists have been using term infinitive for form more often called continuative (連用形) (し, 助け for these 2 verbs).

By the way, see also comparison of 手{て}伝{つだ}う, 助{たす}ける and 救{すく}う.

Term infinitive for 連用形 was probably introduced by Samuel E. Martin, and was also used by Bjarke Frellesvig, while Alexander Vovin used term converb.

FWIW, I personally think the term "infinitive" is so tightly tied to the grammar of verbs in European languages that it is misleading to use it for Japanese, where verbs function very differently. Likewise for many of the other common terms in English for conjugated verb forms. For instance, "infinitive" is often described as a "non-finite verb form", which in turn "is a form of a verb that lacks inflection (conjugation) for number or person". Which, in Japanese, is all of them.

For the OP, please be aware that the Japanese language has no grammatical number (no plurals, really), and no grammatical person (verbs don't change based on who does the verb).  For person, consider "I/we/you do, he/she/it does" in English, "yo hago, tu haces, él/ella hace, nosotros hacemos, vosotros haceis, ellos/ellas hacen" in Spanish. But in Japanese, no matter who does it, the verb is する (suru). Verb forms change instead based on the relation between speaker, listener, and subject.

Japanese doesn't have a direct equivalent of English infinitives, and you have to use different constructions depending on the verb.

I help her to study Spanish.
彼女がスペイン語を勉強するのを手伝う。
I want her to study Spanish.
彼女にスペイン語を勉強してほしい。
I ask her to study Spanish.
彼女にスペイン語を勉強するように頼む。
I get her to study Spanish.
I make her study Spanish.
彼女にスペイン語を勉強させる。


You might also mention that: (1) instead of NOUN+する nominalized with の, you can use NOUN (e.g. 「彼女のスペイン語の勉強を手伝う。」 = literally "I help her study/learning of Spanish."); (2) with 手伝う, you can specify helped person with を and action noun with で (e.g. 「スペイン語の勉強で彼女を手伝う。」 = literally "I help her with study/learning of Spanish.").

And (3) with verbs like 行く and 来る, deverbal noun with -i suffix derived from given verb (similar to 連用形 of this verb but with possibly different accent pattern) + に + 行く／来る is more direct equivalent of English "go to do something".

To elaborate, and especially to incorporate information from the comments:
As Eiríkr Útlendi says, Japanese has a completely different system of verb conjugation from the one used in English and other European languages. In particular, it doesn't inflect any words for person (1st/2nd/3rd), gender (in the grammatical sense) or number (singular vs plural).
In English, the infinitive is used as a dictionary form of verbs because it's just a single form which lacks those inflections. But in Japanese, every verb form is like that, so that doesn't make sense as a basis to choose a dictionary form. By convention, the dictionary form of Japanese verbs is the [終止形]{しゅうしけい} (literally "terminal form"), i.e. the form used at the end of sentences.
Japanese also doesn't really have a verb form that fills the same grammatical role as the infinitive - but then, English isn't consistent about this, either. Consider:
I must swimming. (wrong)
I must to swim. (wrong)
I must swim.

I want swimming. (wrong)
I want to swim.
I want swim. (wrong)

I enjoy swimming.
I enjoy to swim. (wrong)
I enjoy swim. (wrong)

(And there are other cases where more than one of those might be acceptable, where some are questionable but not clearly wrong, etc.)
Probably the closest thing to an infinitive in Japanese, in terms of grammatical function, is the [連用形]{れんようけい} or "continuative form", also referred to in textbooks as an "i-stem" or "masu-stem". It's used to make compound verbs such as [飛]{と}び[込]{こ}む "to jump (or fly) into". I can't particularly disagree with linguists who translated 連用形 as "infinitive", but from my analysis it's more like a gerund (verbal noun).
There's also the so-called "te form", which is really a contraction (or sound change for euphony) from the combination of 連用形 with a particle て (related to the で used similarly to に, but that's a whole other story). Natural translations often render these as adverbs, depending on context; but I tend to think of them more like gerundives (verbal adjectives).

But it seems like what you're really after are the strategies that Japanese uses to convey the same meaning as the verb phrases in your English example. (Unfortunately it isn't a very good example because suru verbs are a bit special.)
The key insight here is that the English infinitive is actually acting like an abstract noun. When I say that I must swim, or enjoy swimming, or want to swim, in all of these cases I am referring to the act of swimming. One mental model is that verbs like "must" and "enjoy" and "want" here are helpers that participate in forming the main verb, a variation of "to swim". But a probably clearer analysis is that those are the main verbs, and "the act of swimming" is their direct object. That's the answer to the questions: what must I do? what do I enjoy? what do I want?
Compound verbs using 連用形, as discussed above are one such strategy. These verb forms can frequently be used by themselves as nouns; and just as in English, the exact meaning relates to the verb but does not follow a set formula. (In a sense, suru verbs are already this, using an actual noun. 勉強する is "to study", but more literally, it's "to do [the act of] studying".)
Another common formula uses te-form to connect the verbs, where a compound verb isn't accepted. This is naruto's second example: 彼女にスペイン語を勉強してほしい。Here, して is the te-form of する. (The i-stem is し and there is no sound change in this case. Overall する is quite irregular, but this one follows the expected rules.) We translate this as "I want her to study Spanish", but it works more like "her studying Spanish is desirable (for me)".
Another way is to create a noun that can fill the に place of the verb. That might use an i-stem or it might use a nominalizer, such as の or [事]{こと}, or more abstractly like よう or ため. 彼女にスペイン語を勉強するように頼む。works something like "I request for the purpose that she studies Spanish". In this example - as well as 彼女がスペイン語を勉強するのを手伝う - the entire phrase 彼女がスペイン語を勉強する is used to describe a nominalizer. In context, よう and の basically mean "purpose" and "action" respectively, and then we say what purpose or action that is - specifically, the one involving her studying Spanish.
The i-stem + に approach is common with the verbs [行]{い}く and [来]{く}る, as Arfrever points out.
In the case of suru verbs, since there's a noun already there, we can often just use the noun. 彼女がスペイン語を勉強するのを手伝う can become just 彼女のスペイン語の勉強を手伝う, as Arfrever pointed out in comments. Now that we have the noun 勉強 "study", we can't mark スペイン語 with を (we lost the verb, so it's no longer a direct object) - instead, it becomes の (different from the nominalizing の). Similarly for 彼女, which is no longer a subject. We have the noun phrase 彼女のスペイン語の勉強 "her study of Spanish" (i.e. "(study of Spanish) of hers") as the direct object of 手伝う. (Notice that verb has a different place structure from the English "help"; "facilitate" might be a better translation.)
Finally, sometimes you just rely on set forms in the grammar. In Japanese, causative forms are built into the conjugation system - you don't necessarily use a helper verb like "cause" or "make" or "force" (or "permit/enable", which is also a potential nuance of the form). させる is the causative of する, and therefore the ending for the causative of suru verbs.

I do not know if 連用形 and deverbal nouns with -i suffix are related, but they have different accent patterns. See e.g. this, this and Martin 1987: 211.

In English, there are also remnants of formerly more productive system of causatives, e.g. "rise": "raise", "fall": "fell", "sit": "set".
